# MongoDB - Cannot divide by zero error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

trying to figure out why I'm getting this error, my code is below

```
db.assign1.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$courses"},
{$match: {status: "active"}},
{$group: {_id: {"Course Code": "$courses.code"},
         "Total Questions": {$sum: "$courses.total_questions"},
         "Correct Answers": {$sum: "$courses.correct_answers"}}},
{$project: {_id: 0,
           "Course Code": 1,
           "Total Questions:": 1,
           "Correct Answers": 1,
           "% Correct": {$divide: [{$sum: "$courses.correct_answers"},{$sum: "$courses.correct_answers"}]}}}
```

Comment: So what happens if you comment out all of the other stages other than the final `$project`? Looks like you "cargo culted" from other anwers you did not understand. The first three stages basically do what the last one does, except you probably want a `$filter` in there. You can also learn something and just comment out the `$project`, and have a look at what gets returned up to that stage.

Comment: I commented out the project before I posted, and was getting a return result of the total answers and total questions. I wasn't sure how to divide so did some online research and another SO article suggested that I had to do an additional project as divide cannot be used in $group. That's how I came up with the code I posted

Comment: So this is the inherent danger in copying things you don't understand. There is a really simple and clear reason why I asked you to try those 2 different steps and actually "look" at what comes out. "Pipeline" is a "series of steps". Start removing steps and look at what each one does. It should tell you exactly why you get the error with "face palm" efficiency.

Comment: There is no `"course"` array present after `$group`. You named the field that returned the `$sum` from those. The final `$project` needs to reference those names: `{ "$divide": ["$Correct Answers", "$Total Questions"] }`. And you really should not use spaces in property names.

Comment: Thanks for your help